# Restrict GET route in Rails 4 to app only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a JSON hash that the backend processes and serves to our frontend to calculate a map. The JSON hash is rendered from a GET request and is constantly being updated (not cached).

We need a way to lock down the route so that only the app itself can connect to it (stopping bots from pinging the URL to grab the hash). The frontend and backend are tied together in one Rails application (no separate services).

My issue is that ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection::ClassMethods does not support GET and ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token is overkill since I need to restrict the JSON hash to the app (not to a specific user). Request.referrer can be spoofed so I hesitate in checking that.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to reject outside GET requests to a Controller when it is not the app making the request.

Rails: 4.2.6

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to prevent arbitrary programs (ie: "user agents") from making HTTP requests against your server. You can, however, refuse to respond with useful content unless the user agent can prove that it's your app.

What you want to do is cryptographically sign your requests in your client app, then verify the signature on your server before responding. I don't know of any Ruby/Rails library to do precisely that (and I couldn't find any upon a cursory search), but it could be built from existing libraries. Here's a quick and dirty implementation concept:

1. Embed a secret key into the client app.
2. Whenever the client app makes a request, it:

   1. Generates a UUID that will be used exactly once, ever. (A "nonce").
   2. Generate a signiture by hashing the nonce with the secret key.
   3. Pass the nonce and the signature with the request (probably as HTTP headers)
3. When the server receives a request, it generates a signature based on the incoming nonce and the secret key (which it already knows). If the signature matches, *and* the nonce has *never* been used before, then the server returns the content. If either of those conditions are not true, then the server can't guarantee that it's your client app making the request, and thus should respond with a failure.

Disclaimers:

1. This is entirely dependent on the security of the secret key embedded in the client app. If the key is hacked (and it will be, given enough effort on the part of the attacker), then this scheme falls apart.

   1. If you use the same secret key for all client apps (and there's a good chance you'll need to, depending on your app architecture), then if one client app install gets hacked, you lose security on *all* of your installations.
2. This is just an illustration of the general principle, not a fully fledged secure implementation. I'm not a security expert and have not run through all of the potential attack vectors for this plan.

I also suggest reading up on how OAuth works. It solves a similar problem, and you may be able to adapt it for your purposes.